# What's the translation of "huckleberry" in French?

Tags: traduction, botanique

A huckleberry [is](https://www.allrecipes.com/article/what-is-a-huckleberry/) a type of berry found in North America. What's the translation of "huckleberry" in French?

Google Translate and DeepL didn't help. Google Translate mentioned "airelle" but that looks like a different fruit. (airelle is red)

Comment: *Airelle* is not that wrong, as it refers to the *Vaccinia* family. But it's like saying *apple* when you want to know if it's a golden or a granny smith. However, you'll almost always find *airelle* as a direct translation for *cranberry* in french (even though the best translation is *canneberge*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [these sources](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52142/26366), that would be a ***baie de gaylussaquier***.

***Baie*** (like berry) is the generic term for these small fruits but ***[gaylussaquier](https://herbierduquebec.gouv.qc.ca/plante/gaylussaquier-a-fruits-bacciformes)*** (*[gaylussacia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaylussacia)*) is new to me although I recognize [*Gay Lussac*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Louis_Gay-Lussac) in it. Gaylussaquier was coined after the Latin name *Gaylussacia* that was given to this plant in the early 19th century.

As already answered, ***airelle*** is another generic name that come to mind in French to name such fruits:

[image]

Source: *Dictionary of the French and English languages*, F. E. A. Gasc, London, 1877

This particular one is also named ***airelle corymbifère***:

[image]

Source: *Second rapport du Comité sénatorial chargé de recueillir des renseignements sur les produits alimentaires naturels des Territoires du Nord-Ouest et sur les meilleurs moyens de conserver et d'augmenter ces ressources*, Ottawa, 1887.

Comment: I suspect "gaylussaquier" may be a word coined by the Québec government from the scientific name for these plants, so that Québecois won't call these things "huckleberries". I don't know whether it will be any more successful than the Académie française's efforts to expunge anglicisms from the French language.

Comment: @PeterShor The Latin name is much easier to convert to French than the English one so it's its natural translation. *Huckleberry* might have given *heuquelberges* though ;-) just like *kraanbeere/cranberries* gave *canneberges*.

Answer (score 1):

Huckleberries are a North American berry that I suspect is unknown in France; it's not clear there's a French word for them.

[Linguée](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/translation/huckleberry.html) suggests *airelle myrtille* and *airelle fausse-myrtille*. These literally mean something like *cranberry blueberry* and *cranberry false blueberry*.

Comment: S'il y a un nom commun pour l'huckleberry, il doit être québecois, parce qu'ils y poussent.

Comment: À un moment donné il y avait un contributeur vraiment féru de ces sujets fort intéressants, @pasunclue, peut-être qu'un jour il va voir ça et ajouter une réponse, j'ai peur de ne pas avoir ce contact et cette connaissance de la nature, malheureusement.

Answer (score 1):

Termes/sources utiles :

[Gaylussaccia](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/9489113/gaylussaccia) (GDT)
[Airelle à longues étamines](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/18958057/airelle-a-longues-etamines) (GDT)
[Myrtille](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8358067/myrtille) (GDT)
[Gaylussacia/gaylussaquier à fruits bacciformes](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=HUCKLEBERRY&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) (Termium : « Il n'y a pas de nom vernaculaire pour cette espèce de plantes. »)
[Gaylussaquier à fruits bacciformes](https://herbierduquebec.gouv.qc.ca/plante/gaylussaquier-a-fruits-bacciformes) (Herbier du Québec)
[Gaylussaccia à fruits bacciformes](https://numerique.banq.qc.ca/patrimoine/details/52327/2022249) ([*Flore Laurentienne*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flore_laurentienne), Fr. [Marie-Victorin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie-Victorin), 1935, BanQ, 432, 438, 441)
[Vocabulaire des petits fruits](https://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/bibliotheque/dictionnaires/terminologie_fruits.aspx) (OQLF)

Answer (score 0):

Huckleberry in french is "Airelle"

Comment: Do you have a source for this (other than, say, Google translate)? In French, *airelle* usually means [a different, related kind of berry.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/airelle)